# Assigning SharePoint Online Admin role to a Guest User

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-administration, guest-access

Can someone confirm if it's a supported setup, please?

- Invited an external guest via Azure AD
- The guest account has an E5 license assigned
- The guest account has a SharePoint Administrator role assigned.
- External Sharing is allowed (see below)

When trying to open the SPO Admin center, we are faced with this error:
[image]

Interestingly, opening regular SharePoint sites works.

[image]

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? is it a supported setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/customers-revoke-admin-privileges. This is the proper way to establish delegation of admin rights to a 3rd party, however they do need to be an MSFT Partner.
2. Create an account for the individual in your tenant. To simply access the SPO Admin center, they do not need a license. If they're going to access SharePoint sites, they'll need a license.

Comment: Thank you Trevor! This is what I was suspecting too. Thank you for the confirmation.